# xAxis label category overlay when use break in higchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

When I use xAxis categories with breaks the label of  xAxis, overlay like the example below. Does it have a solution? A way to stop the overlay. Is there a way to use breaks with xAxis.categories?

Example: [Breaks bug](https://jsfiddle.net/rrrr2266/354zksjd/2/)

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        alignTicks:false,
        zoomType: 'xy',
        resetZoomButton: {
            position: {
                align: 'left',
                verticalAlign: 'top', 
                x: 10,
                y: 10
        },
            relativeTo: 'chart'
        }, 
        
    },
                    
    xAxis: {
         categories: ["2022-06-06","2022-06-07","2022-06-08","2022-06-09","2022-06-10","2022-06-11","2022-06-12","2022-06-13"],
   breaks:[{
   from:2,
   to:3
   }]
    },
    yAxis:{
        title:{
            text : '%'
        },
        
        max: 100,
    },  
    series: [{
        color: "#e88307",
        type: "spline",
        data: [99.68,99.69,99.68,99.62,99.62,99.59,99.57,99.67]
    },{
        color: "#9d07e8",
        type: "spline",
        data: [99.89,99.89,99.89,99.88,99.88,99.88,99.88,99.89]
    },{
        color: "#0738e8",
        type: "spline",
        data: [98.86,98.85,98.94,98.55,97.42,96.75,96.79,96.46]
    },{
        color: "#07e838",
        type: "spline",
        data: [98.4352499872,98.4351670785,98.5149062688,98.057699388,96.9333442352,96.23770101,96.2581544364,96.0359261498]
    }]
});
```

Comment: Do you have an image of what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Responsive rules should work here to change way of show labels, you can use [xAxis.labels.rotation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.rotation), [xAxis.labels.step](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.step) or [xAxis.labels.staggerLines](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.staggerLines).

```
  responsive: {
    rules: [{
      condition: {
        maxWidth: 1000
      },
      chartOptions: {
        xAxis: {
          labels: {
            rotation: -45,
          }
        }
      }
    }]
  }
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2kzx6n3r/